# Can someone just explain how Jquery Accordion UI works?

Tags: jquery, user-interface, accordion

I thought that if I markup my code with H3 headings, and apply jquery ui accordion correctly, the H3 headings would become clickable, and clicking them would alternately hide or display the content under the headings.

Am I correct?  Because it doesn't seem to be working that way for me.  My headers disappear when I click them.

...So I go to the official jquery ui accordion web page for answers (http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#option-header), and I read gibberish like this:

"header ...
Type: Selector ...
Default: "> li > :first-child,> :not(li):even"
Selector for the header element, applied via .find() on the main accordion element. Content panels must be the sibling immediately after their associated headers."

In plain language, what does that mean?  How do I need to construct my content so that jquery UI accordion works?

Signed,
Very Frustrated

P.S. Here's some HTML below, and below that is the Jquery script.  How would I have to structure that HTML to make it work correctly with that script?

```
<div id="accordion">
<h2>Section 1</h2>

Here's some content.

<h2>Section 2</h2>

Some more content.

<h2>Section 3</h2>

Yet more content.

<h2>Section 4</h2>

Even more content.
</div>
```

Here's the script:

```
  $(function() {
$( "#accordion" ).accordion({
});
  });
```

Comment: why dont you replicate the same on jsfiddle, so that it would be easy  for us to explain why its not working. http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: I have no clue how to use jfiddle.  Please see the code I added above.  How would I need to structure the html code so that it works with the jquery accordion ui script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page you linked to has an example:

```
<div id="accordion">
    <h3>First header</h3>
    <div>First content panel</div>
    <h3>Second header</h3>
    <div>Second content panel</div>
</div>
```

jQuery allows you choose your own selector for the header element, but it also has a sensible default.

For the example above, you can supply the selector as "h3":

```
$("#accordion").accordion({
    header: "h3"
});
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/07bske68/

To make yours work, you'll need to wrap the content in a tag of some description, probably a `div` for this example.

```
<div id="accordion">
    <h2>Section 1</h2>
    <div>Here's some content.</div>

    <h2>Section 2</h2>
    <div>Some more content.</div>

    <h2>Section 3</h2>
    <div>Yet more content.</div>

    <h2>Section 4</h2>
    <div>Even more content.</div>
</div>
```

And then use "h2" as your selector for the headers:

```
$("#accordion").accordion({
    header: "h2"
});
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/j79d76ss/

**Final note:** It's actually possible to make yours work without supplying a header, I've just done that to make things clearer.  The key is that your content was not wrapped in anything. You can just use:

```
$("#accordion").accordion();
```

To get the same effect.

Comment: Well, thanks for trying guys.  I just can't seem to make it work.  It is adding 277 pixels at the bottom of each panel that opens.  Headers also disappear when you click them.  I think the mistake I made was trying to use Jquery UI Accordion AFTER installing (and uninstalling) the Easy FAQ with Expanding Text plugin.  Maybe it left some CSS or script when I uninstalled it that is affecting how the Jquery UI Accordion performs.

Comment: Actually, I think I can make it work.  It turns out there's an option called "heightStyle" which when set to "auto" makes all open panels the same height as their tallest panel.   If I change it from "auto" to "content", it should make the panels only as tall as the content... Trying that...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your accordion markup, every section's content needs to be like below else it will not work properly

**HTML CODE:**

```
<div id="accordion">
  <h2>Section 1</h2> <div><p>Here's some content.</p></div>
  <h2>Section 2</h2> <div><p>Here's some more content.</p></div>
  <h2>Section 3</h2> <div><p>Yet more content.</p></div>
  <h2>Section 4</h2> <div><p>Even more content.</p></div>
</div>
```

[Live demo on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/fs5pu2w4/)

[jQuery Accordion API](https://jqueryui.com/accordion/)